# javascript optional chaining on just one parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to achieve optional chaining on just a single parameter ?

```
setAllProperties(
    Object.values(users).flatMap(({ properties }) =>
      Object.values(properties)
    )
  );
```

I want to make sure that the properties folder exist in the user folder. something like {properties?... [ I have only used tis when there is another folder, like properties?.property_id]

Some users in my database do not have any properties added, to their account, so they will not have a properties folder.

This is causing my page to crash "cannot convert null object".  How can I use optional chaining here?

I tried putting the question mark, but the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional chaining only works when you're trying to access a member of an object directly. But `Object.values(properties)` does not directly access a member; the access is done inside the `Object.values` function, which you can't change. So optional chaining won't work here. You'll need something a bit more verbose.

```
setAllProperties(
  Object.values(users).flatMap(({ properties }) =>
    properties ? Object.values(properties) : []
  )
);
```

Comment: If you want somethin less verbose : `Object.values(properties || {})`

Comment: @OneQ first of all `??` would be more appropriate, but why both instantiate an object and make a function call instead of just using a ternary?

Comment: Because he said that was more verbose. And what I wrote is less verbose

Comment: Why ?? is more appropriate ?

Comment: because you're testing for `undefined` and not falsy in that statement. Even less verbose would simply be to assign a default in the destructuring `.flatMap(({ properties = {} }) => Object.values(properties));`

Comment: I'm not sure if I undersand, with || undefined would not work ?
You're right it would be less verbose to assign a default value

Comment: It will work with `||` given that it's testing against an expected value of an array, but given that the language has a specific operator for testing `undefined` it behooves one to make use of it when appropriate, both to clarify the intent and avoid avoidable side effects.

Comment: Yeah, `??` and `||` work just as well in that case. I'd prefer `??` too, not because it results in different logic, but because it indicates to the reader of the code: "This is to exclude `undefined` and `null` ONLY". Precision of intent is nice.